# Is this jQuery pattern browser-safe: "attr('foo') || 'default'"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

This seems like a neat way to read a value from a data attribute or use a default value if it's not present:

```
var confirmMessage = resourceDiv.attr("data-confirm-delete-text") || "Delete this resource?";
```

It relies on `undefined` (which is returned if the attribute isn't present) being falsey.  Is this a browser-safe solution?  If not, what's a nicer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's browser safe. Just be wary of using it on values which are falsy when valid, eg `0`, or `false`. Also note that you'll find some people who don't like using that construct, but that's mostly for code readability issues, not browser support.

The alternatives are an `if` statement:

```
var confirmMessage = resourceDiv.attr("data-confirm-delete-text");
if (!confirmMessage)
  confirmMessage = "Delete this resource?";
```

Or a ternary:

```
var confirmMessage = resourceDiv.attr("data-confirm-delete-text") ? resourceDiv.attr("data-confirm-delete-text") : 'Delete this resource?';
```

As you can see, they are much more verbose, and in the case of the ternary, may include some redundancy.

Comment: Thanks Rory, that's great.  In this sort of instance I'm not concerned about the other falsy values as it's only used for interface messages (eg a confirmation in this instance).  cheers, max